# how can change another classes with hover with one class? without js, just css

Tags: html, css, hover

good time. I have several tags with right classes and I want to apply the style I want to the rest of the right classes when I hover over at least one of these divs.(remember that i cant change html files, just css file.) here see the pic.
[image]
[image]
[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #d5d8dc;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.right {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
}

.right:nth-child(1) {
  left: 20%;
}

.right:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: -140px;
  top: 140px;
}

.right:nth-child(3) {
  left: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
}

.right:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: +140px;
  top: 140px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.left {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
}

.left:nth-child(5) {
  left: 0;
  top: 20%;
}

.left:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: -60px;
  top: 220px;
}

.left:nth-child(7) {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.left:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: -140px;
  top: 220px;
}

.left:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}

.right:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you only need the right green square to be in front when it's hovered or do you want to apply it for the left red square as well ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it on the container like this:

```css
#container:hover .right {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #d5d8dc;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.right {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
}

.right:nth-child(1) {
  left: 20%;
}

.right:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: -140px;
  top: 140px;
}

.right:nth-child(3) {
  left: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
}

.right:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 140px;
  top: 140px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.left {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
}

.left:nth-child(5) {
  left: 0;
  top: 20%;
}

.left:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: -60px;
  top: 220px;
}

.left:nth-child(7) {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.left:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: -140px;
  top: 220px;
}

#container:hover .right {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

([Codepen](https://codepen.io/arctic360/pen/xxJGpvV))

Or if you just want to hover on the .right divs then the only way to do that with CSS-only is with modern selectors like `:has()` like this

```css
#container:has(.right:hover) .right {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #d5d8dc;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.right {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
}

.right:nth-child(1) {
  left: 20%;
}

.right:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: -140px;
  top: 140px;
}

.right:nth-child(3) {
  left: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
}

.right:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: 140px;
  top: 140px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.left {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
}

.left:nth-child(5) {
  left: 0;
  top: 20%;
}

.left:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: -60px;
  top: 220px;
}

.left:nth-child(7) {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.left:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: -140px;
  top: 220px;
}

#container:has(.right:hover) .right {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

([Codepen](https://codepen.io/arctic360/pen/ZEjGrYz))

But the `:has()` selector is yet to land in Firefox, but hopefully soon. https://caniuse.com/css-has

Comment: I edited your answer so that it contains your code so if the pen are changed or deleted the code will still be available here

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Glenn Flannagan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15831447/glenn-flannagan) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74897839/17684809), If you want to make the green square (`.right`) in front only when it's hovered (not when the container is hovered), you don't need to use `has`, you could change `left` `z-index` using the `~` sibling selector.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #d5d8dc;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

.right {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.right:nth-child(1) {
  left: 20%;
}

.right:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: -140px;
  top: 140px;
}

.right:nth-child(3) {
  left: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
}

.right:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: +140px;
  top: 140px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.left {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  position: absolute;
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.left:nth-child(5) {
  left: 0;
  top: 20%;
}

.left:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  right: -60px;
  top: 220px;
}

.left:nth-child(7) {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.left:nth-child(8) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: -140px;
  top: 220px;
}

.right:hover~.left {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

Note that if you want to change the `.right` style you will need to select previous elements in some case (which is not well supported)