# how to change direction of div with one class to be square

Tags: html, css

I want a code to be the same of this picture

[image]

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #D5D8DC;
}

.right {
  background-color: #2ECC71;
  height: 320px;
  width: 40px;
}

.left {
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  height: 320px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

----we should not edit html code -----

please help me
I try hard but I cant solve it
I want to set position for each div, but I cant . because 4 div have one class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can change another classes with hover with one class? without js, just css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74897740/how-can-change-another-classes-with-hover-with-one-class-without-js-just-css)

Answer (score 0):

You can select a specific element with CSS `nth-child(n)` selector and set the element's position to absolute, allowing you to play around with its position.

[nth-child(n) CSS selector description](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.php)

[position CSS property description](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

```css
#container {
position: relative;
}
#container>div:nth-child(1) {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 10px solid red;
}

#container>div:nth-child(2) {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 10px solid blue;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```